# Error in bitbucket-pipeline: docker stack deploy requires API version 1.25, but the Docker daemon API version is

Tags: docker, bitbucket, docker-swarm, bitbucket-pipelines

When I try to deploy from Bitbucket Pipeline:
`docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml --with-registry-auth myapp`

receive err: `docker stack deploy requires API version 1.25, but the Docker daemon API version is`

On manager:

```
✗ docker version
Client:
 Version:       18.03.0-ce-rc4
 API version:   1.37
```

When try deploy from local machine OK

locally:

```
✗ docker version
Client:
 Version:       18.03.0-ce-rc4
 API version:   1.37
```

Comment: What about the server versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the API version is blank, it usually means it can't access, or doesn't have permission to access the docker API.

Check the client bundle and be sure you are sourcing it properly.

Comment: Thanks so much. It seems to understand Docker error messages need to be a bit of a medium. After `docker info` now err: `failed to append certificates from PEM file: "/root/.docker/ca.pem"`. And seems like Bitbucket lost line break characters in Settings>Pipeline>Environment variables so as through a web interface and through the API